# Fix a broken apache2 install on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, reinstall

I accidentally broke my apache2 install, and was wondering if I could completely remove apache2 and everything related to it, and then completely reinstall it starting from scratch?

Comment: If you have error messages, please add them to your question.

Comment: Yes, we need actual details. /var/log/apache2/ should have some such logs. /var/log/syslog too.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `dpkg --purge PACKAGENAME`? This should remove the package with all it's config files.

Comment: Sorry I will make my install setup clearer. I have a dedicated box running debian squeeze with webmin for administration. It was working but now it throws errors when I want to start apache. Odd things about errors in apache2.conf. I got it to reinstall (I think) but it didn't make an apache2.conf so webmin now complains bitterly. 

P.S. I think I may just reinstall debian again and follow the tutorial at [woodel.com](http://woodel.com) this weekend when I have time.
P.P.S. Is there a way to remotely install debian with out massive terminal hacking?

Comment: Maybe you could post the error messages on http://pastebin.com/ or even better update your question? Normally `dpkg --purge` and afterwards `dpkg --install` should reset the package to its basic state. Maybe if only the configuration is broken try `dpkg --configure`to try and fix the configuration.